# Testing Launcher icon on Nokia Qt SDK

Tags: qt, nokia

How do you test the application icon in the Nokia Qt SDK Simulator? The one which starts when u run the the application from within the Qt Creator.

I like to see how it works & how the sizing works out, but seems there is no App Launcher process as there is in iPhone/Android. Any hints?

Comment: You want to have a view of the device menu from which you can launch your app by pressing its icon? I think that the simulator doesn't have a feature like that. If you want to test your app in a more real enviroment or in device that you don't have maybe the Forumn Nokia Remote Device Access (http://www.forum.nokia.com/Devices/Remote_device_access/ ) could help you.

Comment: Thanks @Mkfnx, that seems to be a possibility. I don't like it much, though. U can reply this as answer if you like. thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to have a view of the device menu from which you can launch your app by pressing its icon the simulator doesn't provide a feature like that.

If you want to test your app in a more real enviroment or in device that you don't have maybe the [Forum Nokia Remote Device Access](http://forum.nokia.com/Devices/Remote_device_access) could help you.